# Spring integration mail imap inbound adapter throws exception after integration flow change

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

I have configured the following imap-inbound-adapter to receive  mails from an inbox.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow incomingMailFlow(MailProperties properties,
                                        MimeMessageToMailMessageTransformer mimeMessageToMailMessageTransformer,
                                        SubscribableChannel errorChannel,
                                        SubscribableChannel notificationChannel
) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Mail.imapIdleAdapter(properties.getImapUrl())
                    .javaMailProperties(p -> p
                            .put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true")
                            .put("mail.imap.ssl.trust", "*"))
                    .errorChannel(errorChannel)
                    .shouldDeleteMessages(properties.getDeleteMessages())
            )
            .transform(mimeMessageToMailMessageTransformer)
            .channel(notificationChannel)
            .get();
}
```

To enable integration testing i changed the the configuration (for testing i want to replace the imapIdleAdapter with test configuration):

```
@Bean
public SubscribableChannel incomingMailChannel() {
    return MessageChannels
            .publishSubscribe("incomingMailChannel")
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow imapAdapter(MailProperties properties, SubscribableChannel errorChannel,
                                   SubscribableChannel incomingMailChannel) {
    return from(Mail.imapIdleAdapter(properties.getImapUrl())
            .javaMailProperties(p -> p
                    .put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true")
                    .put("mail.imap.ssl.trust", "*"))
            .errorChannel(errorChannel)
            .channel(incomingMailChannel)
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow incomingMailFlow(SubscribableChannel incomingMailChannel,
                                        MimeMessageToMailMessageTransformer mimeMessageToMailMessageTransformer,
                                        SubscribableChannel notificationChannel
) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(incomingMailChannel)
            .transform(mimeMessageToMailMessageTransformer)
            .channel(notificationChannel)
            .get();
}
```

UPDATE: I could run the JavaMail debug, but i had to remove some content in order to post the logfile output (max. 30_000 characters)

```
javax.mail                               : Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
javax.mail                               : successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'taskScheduler'
javax.mail                               : getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
com.sun.mail.imap                        : mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
com.sun.mail.imap                        : mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Filter 'requestContextFilter' configured successfully
com.sun.mail.imap                        : mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
.b.w.s.f.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter : Initializing filter 'httpPutFormContentFilter'
.b.w.s.f.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter : Filter 'httpPutFormContentFilter' configured successfully
.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter : Initializing filter 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter'
.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter : Filter 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' configured successfully
com.sun.mail.imap                        : mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
s.b.w.s.f.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter : Initializing filter 'characterEncodingFilter'
s.b.w.s.f.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter : Filter 'characterEncodingFilter' configured successfully
com.sun.mail.imap                        : mail.imap.minidletime: 10
com.sun.mail.imap                        : enable STARTTLS
com.sun.mail.imap                        : peek
com.sun.mail.imap                        : closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
o.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : connecting to store [imap://user:*****@mailserver:143/INBOX]
com.sun.mail.imap                        : trying to connect to host "mailserver", port 143, isSSL false
io.undertow                              : starting undertow server io.undertow.Undertow@7c3ebc6b
io.undertow                              : Configuring listener with protocol HTTP for interface 0.0.0.0 and port 8080
com.sun.mail.imap                        : AUTH: PLAIN
com.sun.mail.imap                        : protocolConnect login, host=mailserver, user=user, password=<non-null>
o.s.b.w.e.u.UndertowServletWebServer     : Undertow started on port(s) 8080 (http) with context path ''
d.e.m.applicationApplication            : Started applicationApplication in 20.603 seconds (JVM running for 21.067)
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : getStoreProtocol() borrowing a connection
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : getStoreProtocol() - connection available -- size: 1
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : getStoreProtocol() -- storeConnectionInUse
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : releaseFolderStoreProtocol()
o.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : opening folder [imap://user:*****@mailserver:143/INBOX]
com.sun.mail.imap                        : connection available -- size: 1
com.sun.mail.imap.messagecache           : create cache of size 0
o.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : This email server does not support RECENT flag, but it does support USER flags which will be used to prevent duplicates during email fetch. This receiver instance uses flag: spring-integration-mail-adapter
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
com.sun.mail.imap.messagecache           : add 1 messages
com.sun.mail.imap.messagecache           : create message number 1
com.sun.mail.imap                        : IMAPProtocol noop
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : getStoreProtocol() - no connections in the pool, creating a new one
com.sun.mail.imap                        : AUTH: PLAIN
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : getStoreProtocol() -- storeConnectionInUse
com.sun.mail.imap                        : IMAPProtocol noop
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : releaseStoreProtocol()
o.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
o.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : This email server does not support RECENT flag, but it does support USER flags which will be used to prevent duplicates during email fetch. This receiver instance uses flag: spring-integration-mail-adapter
p.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : found 1 new messages
o.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : Received 1 messages
o.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : USER flags are supported by this mail server. Flagging message with 'spring-integration-mail-adapter' user flag
javax.activation                         : MailcapCommandMap: load HOME
javax.activation                         : new MailcapFile: file /home/mailAppUser/.mailcap
javax.activation                         : MailcapCommandMap: load SYS
javax.activation                         : new MailcapFile: file /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/mailcap
javax.activation                         : MailcapCommandMap: load JAR
javax.activation                         : MailcapCommandMap: getResources
javax.activation                         : MailcapCommandMap: URL jar:file:/var/application/application_customer_1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/META-INF/mailcap
javax.activation                         : new MailcapFile: InputStream
javax.activation                         : parse: text/plain;;      x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain
javax.activation                         :   Type: text/plain
javax.activation                         :     Command: content-handler, Class: com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain
...more conten parser ...
javax.activation                         : Merging commands for type text/*
javax.activation                         : MailcapCommandMap: successfully loaded mailcap file: /META-INF/mailcap.default
javax.activation                         : MailcapCommandMap: createDataContentHandler for multipart/alternative
javax.activation                         :   search DB #1
javax.activation                         :   search DB #2
javax.activation                         :   search fallback DB #1
javax.activation                         :     got content-handler
javax.activation                         :       class com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : connection pool current size: 1   pool size: 1
com.sun.mail.imap                        : pool is full, not adding an Authenticated connection
o.s.i.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter        : received 1 mail messages
o.s.i.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter        : Task completed successfully. Re-scheduling it again right away.
o.s.i.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter        : waiting for mail
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : getStoreProtocol() - connection available -- size: 1
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : getStoreProtocol() -- storeConnectionInUse
com.sun.mail.imap                        : IMAPProtocol noop
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : releaseStoreProtocol()
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : getStoreProtocol() borrowing a connection
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : getStoreProtocol() - connection available -- size: 1
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : getStoreProtocol() -- storeConnectionInUse
o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'incomingMailFlow.channel#0', message: GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}]
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : releaseFolderStoreProtocol()
o.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : opening folder [imap://user:*****@mailserver:143/INBOX]
com.sun.mail.imap                        : connection available -- size: 1
com.sun.mail.imap.messagecache           : create cache of size 0
o.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : This email server does not support RECENT flag, but it does support USER flags which will be used to prevent duplicates during email fetch. This receiver instance uses flag: spring-integration-mail-adapter
o.s.integration.filter.MessageFilter     : incomingMailFlow.org.springframework.integration.filter.MessageFilter#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}]
d.e.m.i.n.i.m.UniqueMimeMessageIdFilter  : Storing the message id <<1dacefec9d29bcaeda907d98@customer-cust.com>>
o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : Listing entities:
o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : de.company.application.mail.domain.MailIdEntity{messageId=<1dacefec9d29bcaeda907d98@customer-cust.com>, id=1266391}
o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'incomingMailFlow.channel#1', message: GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}]
o.s.i.t.MessageTransformingHandler       : incomingMailFlow.org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}]
i.m.MimeMessageToMailMessageTransformer : transforming mail: org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c
javax.activation                         : MailcapCommandMap: createDataContentHandler for text/plain
javax.activation                         :   search DB #1
javax.activation                         :     got content-handler
javax.activation                         :       class com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain
com.sun.mail.imap                        : IMAPProtocol noop
o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is de.company.application.integration.notification.incoming.exception.MailMessageTransformerException: Failed to parse mail message data from mime message, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}], headers={id=e015fc76-8c9c-f8b8-9d3f-b4775569ee11, timestamp=1551259380881}] for original GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}]
o.s.i.router.MethodInvokingRouter        : errorRouterFlow.org.springframework.integration.router.MethodInvokingRouter#0 received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is de.company.application.integration.notification.incoming.exception.MailMessageTransformerException: Failed to parse mail message data from mime message, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}], headers={id=e015fc76-8c9c-f8b8-9d3f-b4775569ee11, timestamp=1551259380881}] for original GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}]
d.e.m.integration.error.ErrorRouter      : Routing org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is de.company.application.integration.notification.incoming.exception.MailMessageTransformerException: Failed to parse mail message data from mime message, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}] to channel unknownErrorChannel
o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : preSend on channel 'unknownErrorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is de.company.application.integration.notification.incoming.exception.MailMessageTransformerException: Failed to parse mail message data from mime message, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}], headers={id=e015fc76-8c9c-f8b8-9d3f-b4775569ee11, timestamp=1551259380881}] for original GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}]
o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : unknownErrorLogger received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is de.company.application.integration.notification.incoming.exception.MailMessageTransformerException: Failed to parse mail message data from mime message, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}], headers={id=e015fc76-8c9c-f8b8-9d3f-b4775569ee11, timestamp=1551259380881}] for original GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}]
 WARN o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is de.company.application.integration.notification.incoming.exception.MailMessageTransformerException: Failed to parse mail message data from mime message, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:95)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:203)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter.lambda$createMessageSendingTask$0(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:216)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is de.company.application.integration.notification.incoming.exception.MailMessageTransformerException: Failed to parse mail message data from mime message, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, timestamp=1551259380290}]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:107)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.java:90)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:89)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: de.company.application.integration.notification.incoming.exception.MailMessageTransformerException: Failed to parse mail message data from mime message
    at de.company.application.integration.notification.incoming.mail.MimeMessageToMailMessageTransformer.transform(MimeMessageToMailMessageTransformer.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeHandlerMethod(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:574)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:312)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:104)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: de.company.application.integration.notification.incoming.exception.CreateMimeParserException: Parser for mime message could not be created
    at de.company.application.integration.notification.incoming.mail.IncomingMailParser.getMimeMessageParser(IncomingMailParser.java:47)
    at de.company.application.integration.notification.incoming.mail.MimeMessageToMailMessageTransformer.transform(MimeMessageToMailMessageTransformer.java:38)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: A7 BAD Error in IMAP command FETCH: Invalid messageset (0.000 + 0.000 secs).
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream.fill(IMAPInputStream.java:159)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream.read(IMAPInputStream.java:192)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:139)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain.getContent(text_plain.java:98)
    at javax.activation.DataSourceDataContentHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:795)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:542)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.getContent(MimeBodyPart.java:657)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.util.MimeMessageParser.parse(MimeMessageParser.java:96)
    at de.company.application.integration.notification.incoming.mail.IncomingMailParser.getMimeMessageParser(IncomingMailParser.java:45)
    ... 46 more

o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'unknownErrorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is de.company.application.integration.notification.incoming.exception.MailMessageTransformerException: Failed to parse mail message data from mime message, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@5905215c, headers={id=49d23354-389d-e998-83f6e0a5bb3d, 
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : getStoreProtocol() - no connections in the pool, creating a new one
com.sun.mail.imap                        : AUTH: PLAIN
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : getStoreProtocol() -- storeConnectionInUse
com.sun.mail.imap                        : IMAPProtocol noop
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : releaseStoreProtocol()
o.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
o.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : This email server does not support RECENT flag, but it does support USER flags which will be used to prevent duplicates during email fetch. This receiver instance uses flag: spring-integration-mail-adapter
o.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : found 0 new messages
o.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : Received 0 messages
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : connection pool current size: 1   pool size: 1
com.sun.mail.imap                        : pool is full, not adding an Authenticated connection
com.sun.mail.imap.connectionpool         : releaseFolderStoreProtocol()
o.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : opening folder [imap://user:*****@mailserver:143/INBOX]
com.sun.mail.imap                        : connection available -- size: 1
com.sun.mail.imap.messagecache           : create cache of size 0
o.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : This email server does not support RECENT flag, but it does support USER flags which will be used to prevent duplicates during email fetch. This receiver instance uses flag: spring-integration-mail-adapter
com.sun.mail.imap.messagecache           : add 4 messages
com.sun.mail.imap.messagecache           : create message number 1
com.sun.mail.imap.messagecache           : create message number 2
com.sun.mail.imap.messagecache           : create message number 3
com.sun.mail.imap.messagecache           : create message number 4
```

UPDATE 2: i checked the mail server logfiles and found a pattern that occurs when application fails to read the mails. The application fails when there are two imap logins

```
Feb 27 10:22:59 Ubuntu postfix/smtpd[3947]: connect from unknown[host-ip]
Feb 27 10:22:59 Ubuntu postfix/smtpd[3947]: A7D87C2074: client=unknown[host-ip]
Feb 27 10:22:59 Ubuntu postfix/cleanup[3949]: A7D87C2074: message-id=<1dace980154b4fec9d29bcaed@customer.com>
Feb 27 10:22:59 Ubuntu postfix/qmgr[1380]: A7D87C2074: from=<sender@customer.com>, size=5941, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 27 10:22:59 Ubuntu postfix/smtpd[3947]: disconnect from unknown[host-ip] helo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Feb 27 10:22:59 Ubuntu postfix/local[3950]: A7D87C2074: to=<inbox@domain.com>, orig_to=<recipient@customer.com>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Feb 27 10:22:59 Ubuntu postfix/qmgr[1380]: A7D87C2074: removed
Feb 27 10:23:00 Ubuntu dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<inbox>, method=PLAIN, rip=spring-application-ip, lip=spring-application-ip, mpid=3954, secured, session=<mgBQuNyCOtIKOi7N>
Feb 27 10:23:00 Ubuntu dovecot: imap(inbox): Logged out in=516 out=8630
Feb 27 10:23:00 Ubuntu dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<inbox>, method=PLAIN, rip=spring-application-ip, lip=spring-application-ip, mpid=3959, secured, session=<8z5auNyCPNIKOi7N>
Feb 27 10:23:00 Ubuntu dovecot: imap(inbox): Logged out in=352 out=1305
```

If the mails are processed successfully, the logfile entry looks like

```
Feb 27 10:24:18 Ubuntu postfix/smtpd[3964]: connect from unknown[host-ip]
Feb 27 10:24:18 Ubuntu postfix/smtpd[3964]: 49C78C2074: client=unknown[host-ip]
Feb 27 10:24:18 Ubuntu postfix/cleanup[3949]: 49C78C2074: message-id=<00014af9-91a9-441a-a0a@customer.com>
Feb 27 10:24:18 Ubuntu postfix/qmgr[1380]: 49C78C2074: from=<sender@customer.com>, size=3023, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 27 10:24:18 Ubuntu postfix/local[3950]: 49C78C2074: to=<inbox@domain.com>, orig_to=<recipient@customer.com>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Feb 27 10:24:18 Ubuntu postfix/qmgr[1380]: 49C78C2074: removed
Feb 27 10:24:18 Ubuntu postfix/smtpd[3964]: disconnect from unknown[host-ip] helo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Feb 27 10:24:18 Ubuntu dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<inbox>, method=PLAIN, rip=spring-application-ip, lip=spring-application-ip, mpid=3971, secured, session=<Z1v9vNyCPtIKOi7N>
Feb 27 10:24:18 Ubuntu dovecot: imap(inbox): Logged out in=1137 out=18905
Feb 27 10:24:51 Ubuntu postfix/qmgr[1380]: 9578BC1FDE: from=<>, size=2044, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

Update3: after i changed the deleteMessage flag to false, the error does not occur anymore. So if the mails are deleted with ImapIdleChannelAdapterSpec.shouldDeleteMessages(true) the error occurs occasionally. If it set to false, the error does never occur.

Comment: It's hard to say; try adding `javax.mail.debug=true` to the javamail properties to see if it provides any clues.

Comment: The ` A7 BAD Error in IMAP command FETCH: Invalid messageset` is not Spring Integration related issue. Looks like there is something wrong iwth your IMAP server...

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using?  What mail server are you using?  And yes, please include the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).

Comment: I found two dependecies in my project: javax.mail 1.5.5 (from com.sun.mail) and javax.mail-api 1.5.5. The mail server is dovecot running on ubuntu. I will not be able to deliver the JavaMail debug output until tomorrow.

Comment: I have posted the more content of the java mail debug output on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/pAzcKhaz)

Comment: I have updated my post with the logfiles of the mail server.

Comment: After setting deleteMessages to false the error does not occur anymore. In the mail server logfiles i can see, that the application is now only using on login and then only logs out when i stop the application. With the deleteMessage set true the application logs in and out on every request to the mail server.